# Add the data to the tables by using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Q: Add the data to the tables. Be sure to use the sequences for the PKs.

I need to add data into the table that I had made but there is some error that said "SQL command not properly ended "

Codes :

```
INSERT INTO actors(actor_id, stage_name, first_name, last_name, birth_date)
VALUES(actor_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Brad Pitt', 'William', 'Pitt', TO_DATE('18-DEC-1963','DD-MON-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO actors(actor_id, stage_name, first_name, last_name, birth_date)
VALUES(actor_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Amitabh Bachchan', 'Amit', 'Srivastav', TO_DATE('11-10-1942','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO actors(actor_id, stage_name, first_name, last_name, birth_date)
VALUES(actor_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Aamir Khan', 'Aamir', 'Hussain Khan', TO_DATE('14 March 1965','DD Month YYYY'));
INSERT INTO actors(actor_id, stage_name, first_name, last_name, birth_date)
VALUES(actor_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Akshay Kumar', 'Rajiv', 'Bhatia', TO_DATE('09/09/1967','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested code you posted (on my database, using SQL*Plus); it is correctly written, there's nothing wrong with it.

I presume you're using SQL Workshop. If so, then: it runs statement-by-statement, so you'd have to highlight one `INSERT` and run it. Then highlight another, run it. And so forth.

Or, enclose the whole code you wrote into `BEGIN-END` (and make it an anonymous PL/SQL block) and then run it *at once*, e.g.

```
begin
  insert into actors (actor_id, ...) values (actor_id_seq.nextval, ...);
  insert into actors ...
  insert into actors ...
end;
/
```